# Facebook SDK : openActiveSession does not have additional permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Inside the `ActivityStarting` activity we have the login fragment and on Auth button is clicked we run:

```
private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed() ) {
        Log.d("Session:",  "New session" );

        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                .setPermissions(permissions)
                .setCallback(statusCallback));

    } else {
        Log.d("Session:", "Session is null");
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }

}
```

The problem is that if the user cancels the first dialog and presses again to login  [`openActiveSession`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/#openActiveSession) creates a a new session but it has only the default permissions as the doc correctly states. How can I use `openActiveSession` or something similar with the List of permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I am totally understanding your question, but if you have an existing Session, you can always call requestNewReadPermissions() on it.